# Can't assign request.payload values in query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, hapi.js

I'm developing a simple app with Node/Hapi/Mongodb, but running into a strange issue. Below is the route that handles adding/updating scores; when I send some data to this endpoint through Insomnia/Postman it works as expected. However, when this POST is coming from a different app I'm getting strange results; the value is always null for every field (again this only happens when the POST is coming from another site, but I've logged out the request payload and can see that the data is correct, just gets set to null when assigning to an object, or trying to use it a query)

```
server.route({
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/update-score',
    handler: (request, h) => {
        var scores = db.collection('scores');

        var updateScore = new Promise((resp, rej) => {
            console.log('payload ', request.payload);
            scores.findOneAndUpdate({customerID: request.payload.customerID}, {$set: {customerID: request.payload.customerID, customerName: request.payload.customerName, highScore: request.payload.highScore}}, {upsert: true}, (err, res) => {
                if (err) {
                    return rej(err);
                }
                else {
                    return resp(res);
                }
            })
        });

        return updateScore;
    }
});
```

The console logs out the request payload correctly, but its null/undefined when the query tries to use it. I have also tried creating two objects, outside the mongo method call (like below), and after console logging these pre-defined objects out the value was null there as well; even though I can console.log the request.payload after defining these objects and the data is good.

```
server.route({
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/update-score',
    handler: (request, h) => {
        var scores = db.collection('scores');

        var queryObj = { 
           customerID: request.payload.customerID
        };

        var updateObj = {
           $set: {
              customerName: request.payload.customerName,
              highScore: request.payload.highScore
           }
        }
        var updateScore = new Promise((resp, rej) => {
            console.log('again ', request.payload);
            scores.findOneAndUpdate(queryObj, updateObj, {upsert: true}, (err, res) => {
                if (err) {
                    return rej(err);
                }
                else {
                    return resp(res);
                }
            })
        });

        return updateScore;
    }
});
```

Logging the `queryObj` and `valueObj` would show the values are all `null`, even though I can log the request.payload and see the data correctly. Why can't I use the request.payload values anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short, Insomnia/Postman sends an object as the POST body, but I was JSON encoding the POST from the app; just needed to parse that on the server!